# Woocommerce: Update price in some of the products in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For a client, I need to let backorders for products but they don't want to charge for those. So, I need to update the price dynamically if they stock is 0 or the stock is less than the quantity on the cart.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'modify_cart_product_subtotal', 10, 4 );
function modify_cart_product_subtotal( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $cart ) {
    if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() < $quantity ) {
        return $product->get_stock_quantity() * $product->get_price();
    }
    return $product_subtotal;
}
```

In case of 0 stock, it works like a charm. In case of a quantity greater than the stock, it charges only for the available products, but the tax keeps increasing even for the rest. How can I exclude those from taxes calculations as well?

EDIT:

If I just update the price of the product, it does it for all of them, not only those above the available stock.

```
function zero_price_for_backorders( $cart_object ) {  
    global $isProcessed;
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {

        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value['data']->get_stock_quantity() < $value['quantity']) {
                $value['data']->set_price(0);
            }
        } 
        $isProcessed = true;  
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'zero_price_for_backorders', 99 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `before_calculate_total` and change `product` price using `set_price` function so that you don't have to modify `subtotal` separately. The rest of the flow will fall in place automatically.

You can have a look at this link on how to change it dynamically:

[Change product price dynamically woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096695/change-product-price-dynamically-woocommerce)

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in this: $value['data']->get_stock_quantity()

Comment: compare both values by var_dump() function, so you will see if there is any type casting issue

Comment: The problem is that `set_price` change the price to 0 for all the quantities in the product line. While I need to do it for those above the stock_quantity.

Comment: In that case, you will need to programmatically update quantity of that product line and then add another product line with 0 price. Meaning you will need to do an add to cart programmatically if its beyond your condition. Let me know if that helps